# I know that using props in the initial state is an antipattern in React. How can I achieve the same result without using the prop in the state?

Tags: reactjs, state, anti-patterns, prop

[Todo app](https://playcode.io/1785092%20-%20here%20is%20my%20example)  In my Todo app, I have a Todos List data, and the user can edit todo titles and save or cancel. Saving will change the data in the state, and in case of canceling, the title will remain the same. That's why I decided to have another state in my Task component: const [editedTitle, setEditedTitle] = useState(title); for saving the value during input onChange, and initializing the value from the prop. I know that using props in the initial state is an antipattern in React. How can I achieve the same result without using the prop in the state?

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

```
function Task({ id, title, done, onSaveTodo, onDeleteTodo, onDoneTodo }) {
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);
  const [editedTitle, setEditedTitle] = useState(title);

  let todoContent;
  if (isEditing) {
    todoContent = (
      <>
        <input
          value={editedTitle}
          defaultValue={title}
          onChange={(e) => setEditedTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setIsEditing(false);
            setEditedTitle(title);
          }}
        >
          Cancel
        </button>
        <button
          onClick={() => {
            setIsEditing(false);
            onSaveTodo(id, editedTitle);
          }}
        >
          Save
        </button>
      </>
    );
  } else {
    todoContent = (
      <>
        <label>{title}</label>{" "}
        <button onClick={() => setIsEditing((prevState) => !prevState)}>
          Edit
        </button>
      </>
    );
  }

  return (
    <li>
      <input
        type="checkbox"
        checked={done}
        onChange={(e) => onDoneTodo(id, e.target.checked)}
      />{" "}
      {todoContent}
      <button onClick={() => onDeleteTodo(id)}>Delete</button>
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: " I know that using props in the initial state is an antipattern in React" - who said that?

Comment: in documentation written that Don’t mirror props in state

Comment: You mean that in this case it's ok ?

Comment: The docs then also says: "”Mirroring” props into state only makes sense when you want to ignore all updates for a specific prop. By convention, start the prop name with `initial` or `default` to clarify that its new values are ignored"

Comment: And one more question, what about using useEffect, if I need not only initial value, but also updated values?

Comment: If you try to sync it with `useEffect` then you have to watch out because you will have **two source of truth**: one from props and one locally

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/update-state-source-of-truth-sq57vt?file=%2Fsrc%2FTaskList.js%3A45%2C25-45%2C30 please can you check this is my latest version, it is ok? I use InitialTitle in useState, and during cancel setTitle(initialTitle);

Answer (score 1):

Regarding "don't put props in state" - it's a **general** rule, emphasis on general. When you are "editing" a prop (and using controlled state in your component) you have no choice but to put props in state like you have.

This is how to use a controlled component:

It's inappropriate to use `defaultValue` at the same time as you use `value` and `onChange`. These are mutually exclusive. `defaultValue` is for non-controlled inputs while `value` and `onChange` are for controlled inputs.

Get rid of `defaultValue` and do this:

I believe the change you need to do is simple.

It should just be to change this:

```
        <input
          value={editedTitle}
          defaultValue={title}
          onChange={(e) => setEditedTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
```

to this:

```
        <input
          value={editedTitle}
          onChange={(e) => setEditedTitle(e.target.value)}
        />
```

The alternative is to use an uncontrolled component (just `defaultValue`, no `value`/`onChange`) and use a ref (and no `editedTitle` state):

```
const inputRef = useRef();

<input defaultValue={title} ref={inputRef}/>
```

and then onSave you'd do:

```
saveToDo(id,inputRef.current.value)
```

Comment: you mean                                                                                                                       
        `const [editedTitle, setEditedTitle] = useState(");                              
        <input
          value={isEditing ? editedTitle : title}
          onChange={(e) => setEditedTitle(e.target.value)}
        />`

 In that case I will get empty input for first time

Comment: I need that edited title was same title, expact that during onChange I shuoldn't change original title, beacouse in case of cancel, I should show back initial title, only in case of save title and edited title will be the same

Comment: or I cam write value={editedTitle ? editedTitle : title}, beacouse in case of saving I do setEditedTitle(title);

Comment: @Programmer I misread, you're already in `isEditing` when that JSX is being rendered, I updated my answer

Comment: ok but what about props in state?

Comment: @Programmer it's a general rule (and a good general rule most of the time). But when dealing with form inputs, you have no choice if you're using a controlled component. I've updated my answer to also show you how to do it using a `ref`

Comment: Ok If I should use controlled input, , It's mean that in my case using prop in state, it's ok?

Comment: I just want to make sure, that my code is 'good code' , don't have better alternative, and if I want to use controlled input, it's ok to use prop in state

Comment: @Programmer - there's a common paradigm in react of naming your prop with `initial` or `default` (like `initialValue` or `defaultValue`) and it's understood that, if you provide a component with a prop that is prefixed with `initial` or `default` that the component will "own" that prop and maintain it's own internal state. This presents it's own unique problem - how do you reset the state in a child component when the parent absolutely needs to? And the answer to that question is here: https://react.dev/learn/preserving-and-resetting-state#option-2-resetting-state-with-a-key

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/update-state-source-of-truth-sq57vt?file=%2Fsrc%2FTaskList.js%3A45%2C25-45%2C30 please can you check this is my latest version, it is ok? I use InitialTitle in useState, and during cancel setTitle(initialTitle);

Comment: @Programmer learn to not get so caught up on "is it ok" from somebody else's perspective. Aim first and foremost for the code to be 1. correct and 2. clear (preferably even simple). FWIW, I think it checks both of those boxes. Your next step is to write a test using [react-testing-library](https://testing-library.com/docs/react-testing-library/intro/) to verify your logic remains correct, even when refactoring. Looks great!